Updating or creating table in Prisma using upsert
I have a Notifications model in my primsa.schema
model Notifications {
  id            String           @id @default(cuid())
  userId        String           //@unique ???? does this attribute need to be added
  type          NotificationType @default(none)
  mobile        Boolean
  communication Boolean
  social        Boolean
  marketing     Boolean
  security      Boolean
  user          User             @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

I want to make sure the relation to User is what it should be
model User {
  id            String          @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  accounts      Account[]
  notifications Notifications[]
}

I'm then attempting to use upsert to either create a new record if it does not exist or update the existing one inside of a server action. id is passed to the function via session data of the user
The data for notifications is being passed from my form like this
const update = await updateNotifications(
  session.user.id,
  data.type,
  data.communication_emails,
  data.marketing_emails,
  data.social_emails,
  data.security_emails,
  data.mobile,
);

To the server action below.
 async function updateNotifications(
   id: string,
   type: NotificationType,
   communication: boolean,
   marketing: boolean,
   social: boolean,
   security: boolean,
   mobile: boolean,
) {
  "use server";
  try {
    await prisma.notifications.upsert({
      where: { id },
      update: {
        type,
        communication,
        marketing,
        social,
        security,
        mobile,
      },
      create: {
        id,
        userId,
        type,
        communication,
        marketing,
        social,
        security,
        mobile,
      },
    });
    return upsertNotifications;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating user: ", error);
  }
}

I'm having issues with the userId that no value exists. So that brings me back to the schema and if userId needs to be unique and how does that need to be passed back to the function where I'm using upsert?
Update
I was able to successfully create notifications
async function updateNotifications(
  id: string,
  type: NotificationType,
  communication: boolean,
  marketing: boolean,
  social: boolean,
  security: boolean,
  mobile: boolean,
) {
  "use server";
  try {
    const update = await prisma.notifications.upsert({
      where: { id },
      update: {
        type,
        communication,
        marketing,
        social,
        security,
        mobile,
      },
      create: {
        userId: id,
        type,
        communication,
        marketing,
        social,
        security,
        mobile,
      },
    });

But it is still creating a new notification object every time instead of updating the existing one

upsert needs a where clause so it could find entries that already exist and update them. You have it, but I think the problem is that you pass session.user.id (so the user id?) instead of notification.id. So you are trying to find existing notification by session.user.id, it fails to find anything, and creates a new notification with auto generated id (in your schema => @id @default(cuid())) which has no correlation to the user id.
So to fix it you need to somehow pass notification id here:
const update = await updateNotifications(
  // session.user.id <- remove this
  notificationIdToUpdate,
  data.type,
  data.communication_emails,
  data.marketing_emails,
  data.social_emails,
  data.security_emails,
  data.mobile,
);


The issue is notificationIdToUpdate doesn't exist on first run, meaning if the user hasn't set their preference yet it doesn't exist. I could run a check on if notifications is empty?
Or is it a better idea to populate this upon user creation with default values?

The userId of the notification does match the id of the User

In order for the notification to update, the id ( notifications.id ) of the notification must match the id in the where condition
    "use server";
  try {
    const update = await prisma.notifications.upsert({
      where: { id },    // this id must match with the notification id not the userId

The workflow would be in the edit form, you would be populating the existing data by the querying the database with an existing notification id
